# Dynamically display a single profile image

Tags: codeigniter, foreign-keys, image-uploading, user-profile

I tried different ways, but so far nothing. There are similar topics here but they don’t seem to address my particular situation. I’d like to display a single user profile image from an “images” table with a foreign key link to a “users” table. I have a scenario that works but it’s displaying multiple images with a “foreach” statement. The images are also saved in the local “uploads” folder in the root directory. Here is the code that works for multiple images in the view:

```
<?php foreach($images_model as $images):?>
<img src="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/".$images->fileName;?>" alt="" class="img-thumbnail">
```

Where “fileName” is the column from the “images” table. The images_model looks like this:

```
function get_images(){      
    $this->db->from('images');      
    $this->db->order_by('date_uploaded', 'asc');                            
    $query = $this->db->get();      
    return $query->result();    
}
```

The image-upload section from the controller is below:

```
if($this->upload->do_upload())      {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();         
        $data['user_id'] =  $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $data['fileName'] = $file_data['file_name'];
        $data['filePath'] = $file_data['full_path'];
        $data['fileType'] = $file_data['file_type'];
        $data['fileSize'] = $file_data['file_size'];            
        $data['date_uploaded'] = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
    }
```

[Here is the necessary portion of the ‘images’ table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khaUo.png)

Is there a painless way to display a single image from the “images” table that would take into account the active “user_id” which is the foreign key in the “images” table? In other words, to display a user’s desired image as profile.

Thank you for helping. Appreciate any and all input.

Comment: In your model function you are getting all the record from the table, therefore, multiple images are displaying. Do you want a single user image to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model function `get_images` you are getting all the records from the table so multiple images are displaying.

You have `user_id` in your session use it to get one user record.

**Controller**

```
public function SingleUserImage(){
     $data['images'] = $this->images_model->get_images();
     return $this->load->view('filename', $data);  
}
```

Change model query like this

**MODEL**

```
function get_images(){ 
    return $this->db->get_where('images', ['user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')])->row();
}
```

You have single user record(only one row) so no need to use `foreach` loop

**View**

According to table data that you have provided, image full path is saved use only variable in the `src` attribute of `img` tag

```
<img src="<?php echo $images->fileName;?>" alt="" class="img-thumbnail">
```

**Update:-**

According to your requirement with the loop use this

```
<?php foreach($images_model as $images):
    if($images->user_id == $this->session->userdata('user_id')):?>
       <img src="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/".$images->fileName;?>" alt="" class="img-thumbnail">

<?php endif; endforeach;?>
```

Comment: I would like to keep the function that displays multiple images. I just wanted the added option of displaying only 1 user-profile image. Will try your suggestion and let you know. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just created another function name called 'profile_img' with the code you suggest. But I'm getting undefined variable in the view with this:  

<img src="<?php echo $images->fileName;?>" alt="" class="img-thumbnail"> 

Don't I have to link the view to the function somehow through the controller? Again, I don't want to alter the multiple images code cause that's working fine.

Comment: It does work. Thanks! But if you can suggest the best way to get the user to choose an image and have that single image displayed, I'd appreciate it. Perhaps through the fullPath column? 

Right now because of the 'foreach' loop more than one image are being displayed depending on the user. But at least it's a start and I will try to correct that as well.

Comment: @dreamerdan I've added controller part in the answer for the single user image. Use model query from my answer and view part also without loop. Try it and let me know.

Comment: I'll check it out and let you know. Thanks again.